# macOS 10.12.4 keeps losing Wi-Fi connection

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

I have a mid-2014 MBP Pro which I have updated to macOS 10.12.4.

After running this update, the laptop refuses to connect to any Wi-Fi network.

Needless to say, every device on the network has been reset and they are all able to connect to the house Wi-Fi, with the exception of the MBP. The MBP can see all the wireless networks, but can't connect to any of them. It can also see the hotspot from my phone, but can't connect to it.

Does anyone know of a fix?

Update: This is a bug in 10.12.4

I have reformatted the laptop, installed a fresh installation of 10.12.4. The bug is basically this, if the laptop goes to sleep, your ability to connect to a Wifi network is gone forever.

Comment: There are extensive reports of intermittent WiFi failures in at least 10.12.3 and 10.12.2 and maybe going back as far as the Sierra upgrade. WiFi has always been flaky on my machine since the Sierra upgrade. It's unfortunate that this issue has persisted till 10.12.4 as well.

Comment: anyluck? ive had apple work on this issue by sending capture data in 10.12.3 .4 and now .5 but conneectivity for wifi still broken...trying to avoid the fresh install. to be clear, i can connect and see all wifi networks...just no internet access when connected. internet access is fine in recovery mode..apple believes its a 3rd party app but that's kind of bogus. I did a time machine backup to BEFOre the .4 update and still didnt work

Comment: Well, it just started working again by itself. I didn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

I would totally remove your Wi-Fi service, restart, and add your Wi-Fi service back.

To do this:

- Go to Apple > System Preferences > Network
- Select the Wi-Fi service on the left-hand side
- Click on the cog icon at bottom-left and select Make Service Inactive
- Now delete the service by clicking on the minus sign (i.e. the <kbd>-</kbd> button) at left of the cog
- Click on the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button
- Exit Network preferences
- Restart your MBP
- Go to Apple > System Preferences > Network
- Click on the plus sign (i.e. the <kbd>+</kbd> button) at left of the cog
- In the pop-up window, ensure that Wi-Fi is selected from the drop-down menu
- Click on the <kbd>Create</kbd> button
- Make sure Wi-Fi is on and connected (it should remember your previous settings, but if not just re-add your Wi-Fi network again)

Let me know if this resolves the issue.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Since removing the Wi-Fi service etc didn't work, let's try booting your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you 
   have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Test to see what happens
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Test again to see what happens

Note, booting into Safe Mode will take longer than usual.

**Run Apple Diagnostics**

Okay, time to test your hardware. Follow these steps to run Apple Diagnostics:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Regardless, let me know how you went.

Comment: That didn't work. Just tried it out.

Comment: Okay, I've just updated my answer to include steps for booting into safe mode. Let me know how you go.

Comment: On steps 5 and 7, what am I testing for?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. Just whether or not you can connect to a Wi-Fi network?

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to explain how you can test your hardware.

Comment: I have yet to run the diagnostics step (and I will), however, it seems like an OS issue. I booted into recovery mode and was able to connect to Wifi. I think the problem is with some file corruption which happened with the upgrade process.

Comment: I agree. The only reason I wanted you to test your hardware was because troubleshooting is a process of elimination and I wanted to eliminate hardware as being the issue. Now that you've been able to connect to Wi-Fi from Recovery Mode, you've almost certainly eliminated that possibility (barring an intermittent hardware fault, which I don't believe to be the case). I would do a re-install of the OS and see how that goes. If that doesn't work, you may need to do a totally fresh installation and, if that doesn't work, go back to macOS 10.12.3. I assume, of course, you have Time Machine backups!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your incredibly details answer and help. I had to do a fresh install of macOS 10.12.4. The wifi seems to be ok now. I'm keeping my fingers crossed.