# How can I go back to 10.12.3 without using a Time Machine backup?

Tags: backup, macos

I have mid 2014 MBP. Sierra 10.12.4 just destroyed my laptop's Wifi. After the laptop resumes from sleep, it will not connect to a Wifi network again.

Initially I thought it was a corrupt file or something, so I reformatted the computer and ran a clean installation of 10.12.4.

It worked for a few hours. After the laptop went to sleep, the problem recurred. The laptop can see all Wifi networks but won't connect to any of them.

I don't use Time Machine for backups, instead, I zip and copy my data folders as a backup strategy.

Since the problem with the Wifi is clearly with 10.12.4, I have to go back to a previous version.

How can I do download a copy of 10.12.3 or earlier?

Here's a [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/278673/90709) to my previous question which may offer some more detail about why I need to do this.

Thanks for any advice.